# "Cycle or Multiple Cascade Paths" in relationship with the "ApplicationUser" Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am defining a lot of classes in my project and as an audit requirement, every entity in my project has to have to foreign keys to the "AspNetUser" table, one specifying the user that created the record, and one for the user that has updated it. The following is a sample of "Customer" entity, however, as I said there is tons of entities all with the same requirement:

```
public class Customer {

    public int Id {get; set;}

    // bunch of properties

    [Required]
    public string CreateUserId {get; set;} 
    [Required]
    public string UpdateUserId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("CreateUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreateUser {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("UpdateUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UpdateUser {get; set;}
}
```

Now because there is two foreign keys to the AspNetUser table, when I want to create migration and update the database I get the good old error:

*Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Customers_dbo.AspNetUsers_UpdateUserId' on table 'Customers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.*

I also understand that by adding some codes to the "OnModelCreate" and remove the cascade effect for the "Customer" entity, I will be able to get around this, however, as I said, every entity in my application is going to have this two links to the AspNetUser table which means I have to add that piece of code to the OnModelCreate tons of times each time with the specific entity I'm talking about.

Also, I don't want to cancel the CASCADE DELETE effect as a whole, as it affects the functionality of the app in all of the parts. Any idea how can I efficiently get around this?

I remember back in the days when I did database programming, there was never any issues with one entity having two foreign keys to another one.

Comment: Regarding UpdateUser - Remove this field and create an log for the updates because if two different users update a record you will have only the last one. Which makes tracking history through this single integer field useless. I have the same requirements and moved to history logs rather than second column because of the latter argument.

Answer (score 1):

you should set WillCascadeOnDelete = False by fluentApi, Like This :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
             modelBuilder.Entity<Customer >()
                .HasRequired(c => c.CreateUser)
                //.WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CreateUserId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

             modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasRequired(c => c.UpdateUser )
                //.WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.UpdateUserId )
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```